# Image filter plugin works in one project but not in another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a plugin from w3schools to filter elements. It works perfectly in one of my projects. But now I am trying to use it in another project of mine but it doesn't work. Here is the code pen:

https://codepen.io/zakero/pen/mZYBPz

can anyone find an issue in this, please?

Javascript:

```
filterSelection("all")
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("work-images");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {element.className += " " + arr2[i];}
  }
}

function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);     
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}


// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)

// change is-checked class on buttons
$('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
  var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
  $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
    $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
  });
});
```

Comment: What’s the error you experience? What should happen if it worked? What have you tried to overcome the error?

Comment: There's no error. Everything seems fine but then again the buttons doesn't work. As the code works in another project of mine, I have checked if everything is in its right place or not. I have even imported the whole code from the project where it works without changing anything. It doesn't work in my new project.

Comment: Then the error is that the buttons don't do what they are supposed to do - they do nothing. It's an error, if this is not the expected behavior. You have no error messages, though - but there's no jQuery included in your Codepen, and you have a jQuery function at the end.

Comment: The buttons do something. You can check it in the code inspector. It simply miss a `display: none;` in `.work-images` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have forgotten `display: none;` in `.work-images`.

And for the `is-checked` class. Simply use the w3school code if you do not want to use jQuery.

```
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("filters");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("button");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("is-checked");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" is-checked", "");
    this.className += " is-checked";
  });
}
```

Comment: It was there at first. I had to remove it because the images didnt show up at first. But now it works. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I found the issue as you asked and you chose another answer which did not find the issue in your code. ='( Moreover, the buttons did work in your old code.

Comment: I have been trying to choose both the answers but they only let one. But yeah your answer pinpointed my exact problem. And about the is-checked part. It works just fine so I'll just leave it at that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but it was much easier to write a new filter, than to troubleshoot one.

I changed the **HTML** (added a **data-filtertype** attribute), and wrote a **jQuery** click function that callst the filter (**filterByType**).

Much simpler code, less places to err. If the only thing your wanted was simply filtering the images, then this will do. (This is why it's suggested to write out what you want as a result - the way to that result is not always what you had in mind.)

```js
$(".button").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  filterByType($(this).attr('data-filtertype'))
})

function filterByType(type) {
  $('.work-images').each(function(i, e) {
    if (type !== 'all' && !$(e).hasClass(type)) {
      $(e).hide()
    } else {
      $(e).show()
    }
  })
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  background: #FF6760;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: lato_lightregular;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.button:hover {
  background: #616161;
  color: #fff;
}

.button:active,
.button.is-checked {
  background-color: #616161;
  outline: 0;
}

.button.is-checked {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.8);
}

.button:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 10px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.8);
}

.button-group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.button-group:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.button-group .button {
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.grid {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 10px -16px;
}


/* clear fix */

.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.work-images {
  -ms-flex: 25%;
  flex: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
  border: 11px solid #fff;
}

.work-images img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  height: 210px;
}

.work-images img:hover {
  filter: none;
}

.close {
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  display: inline-block;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="portfoliosection">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="myworks text-center">
      <h2>Our Featured Works</h2>
      <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>
      <div class="work-filter">
        <div id="filters" class="button-group">
          <button class="button is-checked" data-filtertype="all"> All</button>
          <button class="button" data-filtertype="web"> Web Design</button>
          <button class="button" data-filtertype="mob"> Mobile Design</button>
          <button class="button" data-filtertype="photo"> Photography</button>
        </div>

        <div class="grid">
          <div class="work-images web">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/FZED8Yb.jpg" onclick="onClick(this)" alt="Web Design">

          </div>
          <div class="work-images mob">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Jzts3Bm.jpg" onclick="onClick(this)" alt="Mobile Design">

          </div>
          <div class="work-images photo">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/IC4tsi0.jpg" onclick="onClick(this)" alt="Photography">

          </div>
          <div class="work-images mob">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/1x1X5S6.jpg" onclick="onClick(this)" alt="Mobile Design">

          </div>
          <div class="work-images web">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/RckvhDi.jpg" onclick="onClick(this)" alt="Web Design">

          </div>
          <div class="work-images photo">

            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/zjteEnm.jpg" onclick="onClick(this)" alt="Photography">

          </div>
          <div class="work-images web">

            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/i34YqDD.jpg" onclick="onClick(this)" alt="Web Design">

          </div>
          <div class="work-images photo">

            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/2qwcGam.jpg" onclick="onClick(this)" alt="Photography">

          </div>
          <div class="work-images mob">

            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/CoEb43e.jpg" onclick="onClick(this)" alt="Mobile Design">

          </div>
          <div class="work-images photo">

            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/EemBYgT.jpg" onclick="onClick(this)" alt="Photography">

          </div>
          <div class="work-images web">

            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/RdDfJUp.jpg" onclick="onClick(this)" alt="Web Design">

          </div>
          <div class="work-images photo">

            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/FeKM3fp.jpg" onclick="onClick(this)" alt="Photography">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Sorry I had to choose the other answer cause it pin-pointed the problem on my old code. I wish I could choose 2 answers. But your answer is perfect. It worked as well.